# dns server problem

Tags: 22.04

i have disorder on package of snap on linux. i wanted to install some thing by that but suddenly face me with error that error was

```
https://api.snapcraft.io/v2/snaps/refresh": proxyconnect tcp: 
    dial tcp: lookup http on 192.168.1.1:53: no such host
```

and i probably think my dns server is gone through mistake. becuase i have checked out over times my dns configuration file but it was totally changed and after i changed it what before it was but after rebooting, again changed